# find a certain word in sentence in c++

Tags: c++, string, search, char, sentence

I want to write a program that finds a word that the user entered  I think my solution is right but when I Run it, the program shows nothing in the console
anybody can fix it?

```
int main()
 {
   char sen[200],del[200],maybedel[200];
   cout<<"enter sentence :"<<endl;
   cin.getline(sen,200);
   cout<<"which word do you want to delete ?";
   cin.getline(del,200);

   int len = strlen(sen);
   for(int i=0;i<=len;i++)
   {
    if(sen[i]==' ')
    {
        for(int j=i;j<=len;j++)
            if(sen[j]==' ' || sen[j]=='\0')
               for(int k=i+1,t=0;k<j;k++,t++)
                   maybedel[t]=sen[k]; 


    if(maybedel==del)
        cout<<maybedel;
    }
  }



return 0;
}
```

Comment: I presume using `std::string` has been banned from this assignment? It makes the problem utterly trivial.

Comment: Unrelated: You can often save yourself a lot of time when debugging by hard-coding the inputs to known values. A) it always uses the same inputs over and over until you crack the case without fear off typos. B) Much less typing involved.

Comment: Besides usage of `cout` and `cin` that's hardly c++ code.

Answer (score 2):

The major reason for no output is

```
if (maybedel == del)  // <<< this will *never* be true
  cout << maybedel;   // will never run
```

Since comparing "strings" in arrays needs help from `std::strcmp(maybedel,del) == 0` would be better.

UPDATE:

Another attack method is to avoid raw loops and utilize the STL to your favor. Here's a more robust solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "enter sentence :\n";
    string sen;
    if (!getline(cin, sen)) throw std::runtime_error("Unable to read sentence");
    cout << "which word do you want to delete ? ";
    string del;
    if (!(cin >> del)) throw std::runtime_error("Unable to read delete word");
    istringstream stream_sen(sen);
    vector<string> arrayofkeptwords;
    remove_copy_if(istream_iterator<string>(stream_sen), istream_iterator<string>(),
                   back_inserter(arrayofkeptwords),
                   [&del](auto const &maybedel) { return maybedel == del; });
    copy(begin(arrayofkeptwords), end(arrayofkeptwords),
         ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I know there are more bugs, but at least there is now a chance of getting an output.

Comment: We could also skip the vector and just copy the sting stream to cout with `remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream_sen), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                   std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "),
                   [&del](auto const &maybedel) { return maybedel == del; });`

Answer (score 2):

The line if(sen[i]==' '), line 12 of your code , prevents code from entering the block unless the sentence begins with (' ')!
I changed the code a bit and now it works fine.

```
char sen[200], del[200], maybedel[200];
cout << "enter sentence :" << endl;
cin.getline(sen, 200);
cout << "which word do you want to delete ?" << endl;
cin.getline(del, 200);

int len = strlen(sen);
int t = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {

    if(sen[i] == ' ' || sen[i] == '\0') {
        maybedel[t] = '\0';
        t = 0;

        if(strcmp(del,maybedel)==0) {
            cout << maybedel << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        maybedel[t] = sen[i];
        t++;
    }
}
```